# How to efficiently use Schedule Module in tkinter without getting GUI Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, schedule

I am new to python and tkinter and I made very basic program which check IP address ping or reachability in a given time range. I used **Schedule module** to schedule ping but actually after clicking Start Task, the GUI freeze while the code keeps running in the background. Probably the while loop is causing the freeze and I failed to solve this issue even after reviewing all stackoverflow mentioned solutions since no one addressed **how to flawlessly use Schedule module in tkinter.**

I wonder if there is a work-around to implement Schedule module without using while loop or with while loop without causing the GUI to freeze.

Thank you very much.

I made this fast sample for my current case.

**Using Python 3.8.5**

**Target OS: Windows10 pro**

**Tested on VS Code**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from pythonping import ping
from tkinter import *
from win10toast import ToastNotifier 
import schedule

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        
        root.title("Ping Check")
        width=600
        height=400
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.ip_address = StringVar()
        self.seconds = IntVar()
        self.n = ToastNotifier()
        

        IP_Address=tk.Entry(root)
        IP_Address["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        IP_Address["font"] = ft
        IP_Address["fg"] = "#333333"
        IP_Address["justify"] = "center"
        IP_Address["textvariable"] = self.ip_address
        IP_Address.place(x=250,y=70,width=270,height=32)

        ip_address_label=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        ip_address_label["font"] = ft
        ip_address_label["fg"] = "#333333"
        ip_address_label["justify"] = "center"
        ip_address_label["text"] = "Enter IP Address"
        ip_address_label.place(x=60,y=70,width=139,height=30)

        seconds_label=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        seconds_label["font"] = ft
        seconds_label["fg"] = "#333333"
        seconds_label["justify"] = "center"
        seconds_label["text"] = "Enter Seconds"
        seconds_label.place(x=50,y=170,width=143,height=30)

        Seconds=tk.Entry(root)
        Seconds["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        Seconds["font"] = ft
        Seconds["fg"] = "#333333"
        Seconds["justify"] = "center"
        Seconds["textvariable"] = self.seconds
        Seconds.place(x=250,y=170,width=272,height=30)

        start_button=tk.Button(root)
        start_button["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        start_button["font"] = ft
        start_button["fg"] = "#000000"
        start_button["justify"] = "center"
        start_button["text"] = "Start Task"
        start_button.place(x=100,y=310,width=178,height=30)
        start_button["command"] = self.Start_Task

        stop_button=tk.Button(root)
        stop_button["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        stop_button["font"] = ft
        stop_button["fg"] = "#000000"
        stop_button["justify"] = "center"
        stop_button["text"] = "Stop Task"
        stop_button.place(x=330,y=310,width=172,height=30)
        stop_button["command"] = self.Stop_Task

    def ping_ip(self):

        l = list(ping(self.ip_address.get()))

        if not str(l[0]).startswith('Reply'):

            self.n.show_toast("Warning!", "Unreachable IP Address, Error Ping Message: Request timed out!")

        else:
          self.n.show_toast("Successful reply!")

    def Start_Task(self):
        schedule.every(self.seconds.get()).seconds.do(self.ping_ip)
        while True:
          schedule.run_pending()

    def Stop_Task(self):
        schedule.cancel_job(self.Start_Task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

GUI toolkits like `tkinter` are *event-driven*. To work properly, the
`mainloop` must continuously be able to process keyboard and mouse events.
When it is not processing events, it will start scheduled *idle tasks*.

So `tkinter` programs work quite differently from normal Python scripts.

A callback is called in response to activating a control (like clicking on
a button).
An idle task is started by the system after a specified number of milliseconds
when the system is not busy processing events. You can schedule idle tasks
with the `Tk.after()` method.

Basically, the callbacks and idle tasks *are your program*.
But they are run from *within the main loop*.

So whatever you do in a call-back, it should not take too long. Otherwise the GUI becomes unresponsive.
So  using `while True` in a call-back is not a good idea.

In a Python 3 `tkinter` program, when you want to perform a long-running task especially if it involves disk access or network activity, you should probably do that in a second thread. (In Python 3 `tkinter` is mostly thread-safe.)

**Edit 1**:
Instead of using `pythonping` and `schedule`, use `subprocess.Popen` to run the `ping` program asyncronously:

```
import subprocess as sp

# class App:
# et cetera...

def query_task(self):
    if self.process:
        if self.process.returncode:
            # The ping has finished
            if self.process.returncode != 0:
                self.n.show_toast("Warning:", f"ping returned {self.process.returncode}")
            else:  # ping has finished successfully.
                # self.process.stdout and self.process.stderr contain the output of the ping process...
                pass
            # So a new task can be started.
            self.process = None
        else:
            # check again after 0,5 seconds.
            self.after(0.5, self.query_task);

# By convention, method names should be lower case.
def start_task(self):
    if self.process is None:
        self.process = sp.Popen(
          ["ping", self.ip_address.get()], stdout=sp.Pipe, stderr=sp.Pipe
        )
        # Check after 0.5 seconds if the task has finished.
        self.after(0.5, self.query_task);
```

Comment: thank you very much. Would you please apply your valuable advises in my current code so that I get great understanding of callback and idle task. I am the kind who learn with practice or with real case example. Kindly help me understanding those aspects. Believe me your help will have big impact in my professional projects. Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: @user14592768 I added an example of how to call the `ping` program that comes with your operating system.